# logging.NullHandler and __init__.py file location in Python-requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to learn more about Python by looking through the code in popular libraries. The first library that I touched up is `python-requests` by Kenneth Reitz.

What I did is simply `git clone <request_repo_url_from_github>`, and now I'm inspecting the code.

I was looking through the `__init__.py` file in `requests/packages`.

I have a few questions to ask:

1. Why is `__init__.py` inside `requests/packages`, should there not be an `__init__.py` file under `requests` directly? Or is it simple because this is a directly cloned and uninstalled package from github that its like this way?
2. The second question refers to the above code below. What I would like to know is what does `NullHandler` do exactly? I took a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.NullHandler), what does it mean to have a 'no-op' handler. Where would this Handler be used by library devs? I mean, what is special about it?

```
import logging
try:  # Python 2.7+
    from logging import NullHandler
except ImportError:
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
        def emit(self, record):
            pass
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`logging_tree`](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/logging_tree/) which displays all loggers in a form of tree diagram.

Answer (score 3):

From what I remember of `requests`, the `packages` directory contains mirrors of other dependencies which the author decided to bundle along with `requests` instead of adding as dependencies. Personally I would have simply make them dependencies, citing a specific version if necessary, but I'm sure they had their reasons for the bundling approach. I any case, it contains a `__init__.py` so the code can treat it as a module and do things like this:

```
import requests.packages.urllib3
```

If you look at the [`requests` directory on Github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests), you'll see that there is indeed an `__init__.py` in that directory too. If you want to have a hierarchy of packages you need such a file at each level, although in the simplest case it can be an empty file.

If you don't place `__init__.py` in a directory, Python won't recognise it as a package - this is to prevent accidental inclusion of modules from places you'd rather not. You can imagine any number of ways that a directory could be named the same as a package somewhere else on `sys.path` and cause untold confusion, but since there won't be an `__init__.py` in it, it'll be ignored by Python.

To answer your second question, the `NullHandler` is for cases where it's for some reason convenient to have a logging handler, but you don't actually want to do any logging. You might use this if you're using a library which performs logging but in your case you don't actually want to log anything - you install a `NullHandler` to throw those logging messages away, because it's a lot easier (and better practice) than changing their library to strip out the logging code.

In that example, I suppose you could add an alternative logging and simply set the logging level so that no messages are actually produced, but it's arguably easier to just use a `NullHandler` instead.

Comment: @Cartoo Thanks for the answe, I really appreciate it.

Comment: We had a big discussion about why we didn't just include them as dependencies in [this closed issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1384).

Comment: I suppose it is harder for libraries - for applications you can just tell people to use virtualenv and be done with it. It would be nice if you could rely on other libraries to maintain API compatibility, at least within a major version, but I suppose most people aren't bothered with that sort of thing. Coming from a C++ background I guess I might be more used to the discipline than some pure Python programmers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Having an `__init__.py` file in a directory turns that directory into a Python package. It does *not* turn subdirectories into packages as well. If you look at the source tree, you'll see it looks like this (with non relevant-files removed)

   ```
   requests/
   |
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- packages/
       |
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- charade/
       |   |
       |   |-- __init__.py
       |-- urllib3/
           |
           |-- __init__.py
   ```

   This defines a top-level package, `requests`, and also the subpackages `requests.packages`, `requests.packages.charade` and `requests.packages.urllib3`. Defining these packages is necessary to make them properly importable.

   To directly answer the question you asked, there *is* an `__init__.py` file under `requests/` directly. There's just more than one in the entire tree.
2. The `NullHandler` does nothing. It's in place so that calls to the `logging` library can be used unconditionally, even if the user doesn't configure any loggers. Basically, all loggers attached to the logging library get called when `urllib3` tries to log anything. If there are *no* loggers attached, then the logging library emits warnings. Those are lousy, so this is a workaround to make the library code simpler without forcing logging on people.

Comment: Thanks, Its awesome when the 2nd biggest contributor answers your question about the library they contribute to. Thanks a lot, and the diagram makes a lot of sense. But, its different from what it looks like when its cloned on desktop. btw, its the iron-octo-cat gave you away! :P

Comment: Glad to be of help! So that diagram shows the basic structure in the checkout I have on my work machine, but with all the non-`__init__.py` files removed. How does yours look different?